Get existing frame from class name without needing command-line arguments
public class Target extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private Attacker[] FieldIWant;
    /* constructor and other stuff */
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Target().setVisible(true);
    }
}

Is there a way I can get FieldIWant for the guaranteed only running instance of Target from an Attacker object? I have fully qualified class names for both.
All other methods I have found either only give me a Class object instead of the instance or require command line tampering to enable JDI.
Our class has a final project that involves robots with guns that can’t see each other. Our teacher has slightly encouraged “hacking” the runner, and my petty self wants to give my robot eyes.

There is no way to ask the system: "Please give me every instance of this class". It doesn't matter that you know there's only one. You'll have to write, in your own java source files, some code to e.g. assign that to a static field.

So there's no way to do that without initializing the object in a separate class?

You could, in your constructor, assign this to a field. This is usually a bad idea, but, it's somewhat common when building GUIs.

I cannot modify the code of the Target class, though security policies allow reflection. Are you saying that I can access Target from the external class's this?

Then there is nothing you can do, Aaron Liu.

Actually, there is a way. But you need an eye for details to recognize it.

Since Target is a subclass of javax.swing.JFrame. you can find all instances of it in the array returned by Frame.getFrames()
In case there are other instances of Frame or one of its subclasses, you have to iterate over the array and use instanceof to identify the Target instance.
Then, to access the private field you’d have to use field = Target.class .getDeclaredField("FieldIWant"); and field.setAccessible(true);
See

Class.getDeclaredField(…)
Field.setAccessible(…)
Field.get(…)

